# not able to call a function on pagination dojo enhancedGrid

Tags: dojo, pagination, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I tried all the possible ways but it's not working. 
I want to call a function when I move to another page in a dojo dataGrid (during pagination).  I tried the below code, but it's not working...

method one:

```
nextPage = function(src) {
    alert("going");
};

grid.startup();
```

method two:

```
  grid.on("nextPage", function(evt){

 alert("next");
  }, true);
```

method thee:

```
            grid.pagination.plugin.nextPage = function(src) {
                 alert("here");
            };
```

None of these methods are working. Please give sample code which will be called by clicking on any page numbers to move to another page...

Comment: Documentation for this plugin: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Pagination.html.  It does not show any events you can connect to, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269985/dojo-enhanced-grid-with-pagination-need-to-access-number-of-rows-in-the-page.  They were able to implement an enhanced grid with an event handler for `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dirty solution with a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KbZSC/

Main code:

```
    grid.startup();

    var paginatorElements = dojo.query(".dojoxGridInactiveSwitch");
    paginatorElements.push(dojo.query(".dojoxGridInactived"));
    paginatorElements.push(dojo.query(".dojoxGridWardButton"));

    dojo.forEach(paginatorElements, function(element, i){
       dojo.on(element,"click",function(e){
       grid.selection.deselectAll();
       });
});
```

I am getting all elements involved in the pagination process and add an onclick event to each of them, which deselects all elements in the grid using

```
grid.selection.deselectAll();
```

from the other answer i posted for you.

**Please be cautious with this code, as it will break if they change the classes for the paginator html elements** !

You are really persistent !

Comment: i ve edited the answer to your other question with a link to this one !